# which is faster and efficient between generator expression or itertools.chain for iterating over large list?

Tags: python, generator, python-itertools, listiterator

I have large list of string and i want to iteratoe over this list. I want to figure out which is the best way to iterate over list. I have tried using the following ways:

- Generator Expression: `g = (x for x in list)`
- Itertools.chain: `ch = itertools.chain(list)`

Is there is another approach, better than these two, for list iteration?

Comment: `itertools.chain(list)` is pointless.  The function is designed two chain two or more iterators, applying it to just one just gives you nothing but an unnecessary level of indirection.

Comment: As with any performance questions: Measure, don't guess. The "timeit" module is your friend: http://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html

Comment: I was all ready to post "itertools.chain, but it doesn't matter unless it's a bottleneck" when I saw the title, but both options here are just silly. If you really need an iterator instead of using the list directly, `iter(list)` is the best option, but `for item in list` is probably all you need. (Also, don't call variables `list`. You'll get weird errors when you try to call `list(something)`.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The fastest way is just to *iterate over the list*. If you already have a list, layering more iterators/generators isn't going to speed anything up.

A good old `for item in a_list:` is going to be just as fast as any other option, and definitely more readable.

---

Iterators and generators are for when you don't already have a list sitting around in memory. `itertools.count()` for instance just generates a single number at a time; it's not working off of an existing list of numbers.

Another possible use is when you're chaining a number of operations - your intermediate steps can create iterators/generators rather than creating intermediate lists. For instance, if you're wanting to chain a lookup for each item in the list with a `sum()` call, you could use a generator expression for the output of the lookups, which `sum()` would then consume:

```
total_inches_of_snow = sum(inches_of_snow(date) for date in list_of_dates)
```

This allows you to avoid creating an intermediate list with all of the individual inches of snow and instead just generate them as `sum()` consumes them, thus saving memory.